# Animating a Line with PointAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf

I was hoping to animate a `Line` using `PointAnimation`, but discovered that the endpoints of the line are not dependency properties, the individual `X` and `Y` components are.

Would it be possible to subclass `Line`, adding dependency properties for the endpoints (e.g. `P1`, `P2`) and then animate instances of this class with `PointAnimation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Line as a Path:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <LineGeometry x:Name="line" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="100,100"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Now you could animate the StartPoint and EndPoint properties of the LineGeometry.

Comment: Yep, thanks Clemens! Just new started reading about the difference between geometries and shapes.